# Deleting all entries with a specific child

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete all of the entries in my Firebase that have the child parameter

```
isGroup: true;
```

is there any way to do this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var ref = ...
var query = ref.orderByChild("isGroup").equalTo(true);
query.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.remove()
  });
});
```